# How to find if parent Node has no Children

Tags: javascript, asp.net, treeview

I'm not sure if I am using the correct syntax, as my ELSEIF doesn't appear to be firing.  Is this the correct syntax, or what is the best way to test it?

```
<script>
function OnLoad() {
        var links = document.getElementById("<%=TreeView1.ClientID %>").getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            links[i].setAttribute("href", "javascript:NodeClick(\"" + links[i].id + "\", \"" + links[i].getAttribute("href") + "\")");
        }
    }
    window.onload = OnLoad;
    function NodeClick(id, attribute) {

        var nodeLink = document.getElementById(id);

        if (nodeLink.hasChildNodes)
        {
            eval(attribute);
        }
        else if (nodeLink.hasChildNodes == false)
        {
            alert(nodeLink.innerHTML + " clicked");
            window.open("../NewFolder/addNewProduct.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
  </script>
```

If I move the alert/open window by itself it works, so I feel that the problem lies in this line:

```
else if (nodeLink.hasChildNodes == false)
```

Comment: If you can use jQuery, you can do `$('selector for parent').children().length > 0`. You can replace the `else if` with just `else` btw. Or are you checking for `undefined` also?

Comment: Thanks @Arg0n, I could, but not sure how to implement it with what I have.

Comment: shouldn't hasChildNodes() be a method...?

Comment: I also tried this: else if (!nodeLink.hasChildNodes)

Comment: @luciferous Is correct, it should be a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/hasChildNodes) for hasChildNodes says it is a method .i reckon changing it to a method should solve the problem

It should be noted, **hasChiildNodes() considers whitespace and comments**. From the MDN docs

> childNodes also includes e.g. text nodes and comments. To skip them, use ParentNode.children instead.

i.e

```
 if (nodeLink.hasChildNodes())
    {
        eval(attribute);
    }
    else if (!nodeLink.hasChildNodes())
    {
        alert(nodeLink.innerHTML + " clicked");
        window.open("../NewFolder/addNewProduct.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
```

Check the two fiddles to get the difference

- [hasChildNodes fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0kvda6os/) .
- [ParentNode.Children fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t53tecqd/)

Comment: The nodes expand properly using this, but the 'else if' is never fired.

Comment: Oddly, this doesn't even work, same effect:      var nodeLink = document.getElementById(id);
            
            if (nodeLink.hasChildNodes())
            {
                eval(attribute);
            }
            else
            {
                alert(nodeLink.innerHTML + " clicked");
                window.open("../NewFolder/addNewProduct.aspx");
            }

Comment: make sure ,that the target you are fetching doesnt have whitespace of breaking spaces.. Those are considered childNodes.... if you wanna check only for HTMLElements i'd recommend going for ParentNode.children . Check the updated ans

Answer (score 0):

```
parentNode.children.length;
```

if it is `0`, then no child node at all
For example

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('d1').children.length); //->0
console.log(document.getElementById('d2').children.length); //->3
```

```html
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Trying to implement something similar into my example, I used:   if (nodeLink.children.length > 0)
            {
                eval(attribute);
            }
            else
            {
                alert(nodeLink.innerHTML + " clicked");
                window.open("../NewFolder/addNewProduct.aspx");
            }  and it only reaches eval(attribute) regardless if child nodes exist.

Comment: your question says that you have issue in finding child length _How to find if parent Node has no Children_

Comment: Correct, So I would like to only open a new window if there are no child nodes.

Comment: for that, simply use 
`if(parentNode.children.length==0) window.open("../NewFolder/addNewProduct.aspx");`

Comment: This fires whether or not there are children - I don't know why.

Comment: replace the `parentNode` with your element. `document.getElementById()` or likewise. As I shown in the answer

Comment: I did use my Element in the place of parentNode: nodeLink